# Opening an XML in Unity3D when the game is built

Tags: c#, unity, xml

At the moment, my game can open up an XML file inside the editor when I run it. In my XMLReader.cs I'm loading in my file like so:

```
_xmlDocument.Load(Application.dataPath + "\\HV_Settings\\Settings.xml");
```

This class also deals with what the XML should do once it has been read in.

However, when I build the game and run the exe, this file isn't called. I know that I can store this file in the C drive, but I want to keep everything in one place so when I start to release what I'm working on, the user doesn't need to do anything.

Am I doing something silly which is causing the XML not to be read?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Found a work around:

When I build my project, I need to manually drag my XML file into the Resources folder Unity create in the Game_Data folder when it builds the exe.

Comment: Technically this works, but it's quite easy to have Unity include the file automatically so that you don't have to remember to do this every build.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going for the [manual copy solution](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/44592/11127), you can opt to go for the [StreamingAssets](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) route.

Create a folder within your Unity project named "StreamingAssets" and place your XML files in there. Upon build, Unity will then create a verbatim copy of this directory. Your XML files will be accessible at `string path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets";`

Answer (score 1):

To load files on runtime you must use the [Resources](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.html) class. After placing your file inside a folder called "Resources" try something like this:

```
TextAsset propStoreTextAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("resourcename", typeof(TextAsset));
```

Please note, that a TextAsset is not mutable.

Comment: Why the downvote? I mentioned the Resources folder, which is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

StreamingAssets alternative (cross-plateform):

```
public static string BundleFilePath(string filename) {
    string result;
    #if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
    result = Path.Combine(string.Format("file://{0}", Application.streamingAssetsPath), filename);
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    result = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, filename);
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    result = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, string.Format("Raw/{0}", filename));
    #elif UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    result = System.IO.Path.Combine("StreamingAssets/", filename)); // untested
    #endif
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add XML in Unity create in the Game_Data folder when it builds the game exe, not Resource.